# How to find if there is a simple path from vertex x to vertex y that includes the edge e

Tags: algorithm, undirected-graph, max-flow

so I faced this question and I hope that someone can help me in it.

Given an **undirected** graph G = (V, E), 2 vertices x,y and an edge e = (v,u).

Suggest an algorithm to find if there's a ***simple path*** from x to y that includes the edge e.

So the focus here is on the simple path and not a regular path, for a regular path it's an easy problem using the BFS to search a path from x to v and a path from u to y.

I know that the problem can be solved using the max-flow approach but I just don't recognize how to build a new graph that can implement a max-flow algorithm on it so it tells whether the above criterion is achieved or not, I hope for help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does an ordinary BFS implementation find non-simple paths, getting stuck in cycles??

Comment: @clwhisk You can remove the edge e, and find a path from x to v and a path from u to y using BFS for each, notice that the BFS will find a simple path, this can be proven and I assume you've proved it in lectures, so for the problem of finding regular path just do the above things and the path will be (x -> ... -> v -> u -> ... -> y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Without sharing edges (edge-independent)

You could solve max flow with +1 sources at x and y, and -1 sinks at u and v.

Remove the edge e, and set all other edges to capacity 1.

A simple path from x to y via edge e exists if and only if you can find a flow of 2 in this new max flow problem.

### Without sharing vertices (vertex-independent i.e. simple path)

Split each vertex `v[i]` in the original graph into two vertices, `a[i]` and `b[i]`.

For each undirected edge between `v[i]` and `v[j]` in the original, add directed edges `b[j]` to `a[i]` and `b[i]` to `a[j]` with capacity 1.

Also add a directed edge from `a[i]` to `b[i]` with capacity 1 for each vertex `v[i]`.

The idea is that flow must always arrive at an `a[i]` vertex, and leave from a `b[i]` vertex, after passing through the capacity 1 bottleneck from `a[i]` to `b[i]`.  This ensures that each vertex can only be used once.

With this new graph, proceed as for the edge-independent case.

Comment: @CSStudent Note that since you need to find at most 2 augmenting paths, Edmonds-Karp takes linear time.

Comment: I think this allows vertices to appear multiple times, which allows non-simple paths. E.g., the graph {xb, yb, bu, bv, uv} has no solution due to a bottleneck at b, but (my interpretation of) your algorithm would indicate the paths xbu and ybv, implying the non-simple path xbuvby.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz Thank you, I will check this answer later and will confirm if it was found to be true.